# Target and delete elements in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a database with tens of thousand of elements in a table called `ELEM` and I want to remove some of them.

I can't use a simple command (DELETE .. FROM ... WHERE ...) because there is no way to target them directly.

```
select * from ELEM;

+----+--------+
| id |  text  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | text1  |
|  2 | text2  |
```

But I can find their id with :

```
select * from connect where list_id=3

+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id  |  list_id  | elem_1_id | elem_2_id |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 378 |         3 |      2568 |      2569 |
| 379 |         3 |      2568 |      2570 |
| 380 |         3 |      2571 |      2572 |
```

How can I use the variables `elem_1_id` and `elem_2_id` from this result to delete in the `ELEM` table ?

Comment: How do the records for deletion relate to the variables (sic) `elem_1_id` and `elem_2_id` you selected there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you would like to delete from the 'ELEM' table based on elem_1_id  in the 'connect' table you can use an 'IN' sub-query:

```
DELETE FROM ELEM WHERE id IN (
  SELECT elem_1_id FROM connect WHERE list_id = 3
)
```

And if you would like to delete based on both elem_1_id OR elem_2_id, you can do two sub-queries e.g.:

```
DELETE FROM ELEM WHERE id IN (
  SELECT elem_1_id FROM connect WHERE list_id = 3
) OR id IN (
  SELECT elem_2_id FROM connect WHERE list_id = 3
)
```

Comment: Amazing, clean and simple. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
delete e.* from elem as e
inner join connect as c on c.elem_1_id = e.id
where c.list_id = 3;

delete e.* from elem as e
inner join connect as c on c.elem_2_id = e.id
where c.list_id = 3;
```